# Can macrophages phagocytose viruses directly?

Tags: immunology, virology, immune-system

I've been reading that Macrophages, members of the innate immune system, can actively track bacteria and protozoa to devour and destroy them. In the same way, can macrophages devour free viruses, in blood for example, 'actively'? I can understand that random phagosomal uptake might contain virus particles, but by 'active' uptake, I mean the process by which it tracks bacteria to engulf them.

I guess not, but I need an answer. Would be grateful if a source, like a textbook, is provided as well!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site and what we do here. In particular note that there is a [homework](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) policy that requires an attempt from the OP to answer the question for themselves. On that note - what do you know about the immune system and how it works to label foreign bodies?

Comment: If the viruses have been opsonized, macrophages will phagocytose them. I suspect that *direct* phagocytosis of non-opsonized viruses would depend on the type of virus and the surface molecules it expresses.

Comment: @MattDMo thanks for the response! Any example of viruses macrophages phagocytosing non-opsonized viruses?